# Discord.py error. ctx.send does not send messages

Tags: python, discord

I don't understand why my code doesn't want to working. Everything is correct, but ctx.send does not send messages. Please help!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT connected')

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    ctx.send('hello')

token = 'token here hehe'
bot.run(token)
```

I tried everything that came to mind, rewrote everything many times, but nothing works

Comment: Missing ```await```?

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commands.Bot()` requires the intents parameter, which you were not supplying. As well as this, the comment was correct in saying you needed `await` before your `ctx.send()`. Combining both of these fixes produces the desired result.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all()) # added intents

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT connected')

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hello') # added await

token = 'token here hehe'
bot.run(token)
```

Unless you actually want to use all Intents like I have done above, you should only enable what you need. Intents must also be set in https://discord.com/developers/ on the Bot page under the "Privileged Gateway Intents" section.

Let me know if you have any problems or questions, but this code worked on my system. Have a great day/night!